# Content Query Web Part select from more than one type of list/library

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I have a CQWP that is pulling all recently added list items as a display of, "What's new" on a site collection. The problem I have encountered however is that the CQWP's query has to have a default list type that it pulls through information for.

Is it possible to pull through list items from Document Libraries as well as announcement lists and custom lists?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `QueryOverride` property of CQWP. For example:

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Company Announcements</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType"/><Value Type="Computed">Announcement</Value></Eq></Or></Where>]]></property>
```

In your case you will need to specify content type of document library and announcement.
For more information on how to customize CQWP, please refer [this](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/search/label/CQWP).